# How to determine what type of database - Old legacy corporate database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, odbc, top-n

I have access to a legacy corporate database that I can connect to via Microsoft's ODBC for Oracle driver through Visual Studio 2010. Can I query the database to determine what type and version the database is?

Also, will the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver ONLY connect to Oracle servers, or will it connect to others as well?

At this point all I need is a "Top-N" query but haven't been able to get it to work. Here are a few simple queries I've tried, all give syntax errors.

```
SELECT     X_DATETIME_INSERT, X_USERID_INSERT, DB_ACC, ROW_ID, ACD_ACCIDENT_NO, GROUP_ROW_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, ADDRESS_3, ADDRESS_4, 
                  PHONE, INJURY, DELETE_ROW
FROM         EMSDBA.ACD_VICTIM
WHERE rownum <= 100;

SELECT     TOP 100 X_DATETIME_INSERT, X_USERID_INSERT, DB_ACC, ROW_ID, ACD_ACCIDENT_NO, GROUP_ROW_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, ADDRESS_3, ADDRESS_4, 
                  PHONE, INJURY, DELETE_ROW
FROM         EMSDBA.ACD_VICTIM

SELECT     X_DATETIME_INSERT, X_USERID_INSERT, DB_ACC, ROW_ID, ACD_ACCIDENT_NO, GROUP_ROW_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, ADDRESS_3, ADDRESS_4, 
                  PHONE, INJURY, DELETE_ROW
FROM         EMSDBA.ACD_VICTIM
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: The only way to find out the version that I can think of is with a user who has access to dynamic views in the dictionary, like sys. The query is SELECT version FROM v$instance.

Comment: Clearly the type is "Old Legacy Corporate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For top-n, remember that rownum is calculated BEFORE any ordering, so you need to push the ordering down into a subquery. For example, to get the first 100 ordered by x_datetime you can:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT  X_DATETIME_INSERT, X_USERID_INSERT
                , DB_ACC, ROW_ID, ACD_ACCIDENT_NO
                , GROUP_ROW_ID, NAME, ADDRESS_1
                , ADDRESS_2, ADDRESS_3, ADDRESS_4, 
                  PHONE, INJURY, DELETE_ROW
         FROM         EMSDBA.ACD_VICTIM
         ORDER BY x_datetime)
WHERE rownum <= 100;
```

Comment: I changed the ORDER BY statement to ORDER BY x_datetime_insert and removed the trailing semicolon as suggested by Justin Cave above, and it works! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver will only realistically connect to an Oracle databaase.  You can get the basic version information by querying `v$version`

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$version
```

Without seeing the error and without knowing anything about your system, the `rownum` query would appear to be valid syntax (the other two aren't).  Can you post the actual error you're getting?

None of these queries, though, appear to be doing a traditional "Top N" since none of them have `order by` clauses.  They're all asking for an essentially arbitrary set of rows.

Comment: This is the error from the first query: SQL Execution Error. Error Source: msorcl32.dll Error Message: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00911: invalid character.

Comment: Here is the basic version information. Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.1.0.5.0 - 64bi PL/SQL Release 10.1.0.5.0 - Production CORE 10.1.0.5.0 Production TNS for Solaris: Version 10.1.0.5.0 - Production NLSRTL Version 10.1.0.5.0 - Production

Comment: @masospaghetti - My wild guess on the error is that you're including a semicolon at the end of the SQL statement.  If you are, remove it and the ORA-00911 error probably disappears.